# Seed data not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am unsure why my seed data is not loading.

I created five adverts, but when I run `rake db:seed`, only the last advert (a5) displays. In my console when I run `Advert.count` it displays '1', meaning, though I have created five adverts with my seed data only one advert pulled through.

This is my seed file:

```
CategoryFeedback.delete_all
cf1 = CategoryFeedback.create!(name:'good')
cf2 = CategoryFeedback.create!(name:'better')
cf3 = CategoryFeedback.create!(name:'best')

CategoryBusinesstype.delete_all
cb1 = CategoryBusinesstype.create!(name:'Employer')
cb2 = CategoryBusinesstype.create!(name:'Recruiter Agency')
cb3 = CategoryBusinesstype.create!(name:'HR / Business Consultancy')

CategoryJobtype.delete_all
cj1 = CategoryJobtype.create!(name:'Permanent - Full Time Hours')
cj2 = CategoryJobtype.create!(name:'Permanent - Part Time Hours')
cj3 = CategoryJobtype.create!(name:'Temporary - Full Time Hours')
cj4 = CategoryJobtype.create!(name:'Temporary - Part Time Hours')
cj5 = CategoryJobtype.create!(name:'Contract - Full Time Hours')
cj6 = CategoryJobtype.create!(name:'Contract - Part Time Hours')

CategoryPositiontype.delete_all
cp1 = CategoryPositiontype.create!(name:'Intern')
cp2 = CategoryPositiontype.create!(name:'Apprentice')
cp3 = CategoryPositiontype.create!(name:'Entry Level')
cp4 = CategoryPositiontype.create!(name:'Graduate')
cp5 = CategoryPositiontype.create!(name:'Experienced (non manager)')
cp6 = CategoryPositiontype.create!(name:'Management')
cp7 = CategoryPositiontype.create!(name:'Senior Executive')

CategoryCountry.delete_all
cc1 = CategoryCountry.create!(name:'Ghana')
cc2 = CategoryCountry.create!(name:'Nigeria')
cc3 = CategoryCountry.create!(name:'South Africa')
cc4 = CategoryCountry.create!(name:'Libera')

CategoryEditorialapproval.delete_all
ce1 = CategoryEditorialapproval.create!(name:'I want approve changes')
ce2 = CategoryEditorialapproval.create!(name:'I do not want to approve changes (Fastest)')
ce3 = CategoryEditorialapproval.create!(name:'I do not want any changes made')

CategoryApplicationrequest.delete_all
car1 = CategoryApplicationrequest.create!(name:'No application form is required')
car2 = CategoryApplicationrequest.create!(name:'Ask the applicant to visit and online application form')
car3 = CategoryApplicationrequest.create!(name:'Ask the applicant to download an application form')

CategoryRole.delete_all
cr1 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Finance')
cr2 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Human Resource')
cr3 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Purchasing')
cr4 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Management')
cr5 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Partner/Owner')
cr6 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Support')

CategoryFeedbackr.delete_all
cfr1 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'1')
cfr2 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'2')
cfr3 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'3')
cfr4 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'4')
cfr5 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'5')
cfr6 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'6')
cfr7 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'7')
cfr8 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'8')
cfr9 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'9')
cfr10 = CategoryFeedbackr.create!(name:'10')

CategoryAdvert.delete_all
ca1 = CategoryAdvert.create!(name:'Finance')
ca2 = CategoryAdvert.create!(name:'Management')
ca3 = CategoryAdvert.create!(name:'Consultancy')
ca4 = CategoryAdvert.create!(name:'Investment')
ca5 = CategoryAdvert.create!(name:'Construction')

Userr.delete_all
u1 = Userr.new(
  email: 'richill@gmail.com', 
  password: 'password', 
  password_confirmation: 'password', 
  firstname: 'richill', 
  lastname: 'artloe', 
  companyname: 'artloe ltd',
  category_businesstype_id: cb3.id,
  category_role_id: cr2.id,
  staff: 10,
  number: 2089587999,
  hear: 'google'
  )
u1.save!

Advert.delete_all
a1 = Advert.create!(
  title: 'software engineer',
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ac dapibus',
  category_jobtype_id: cj1.id,
  category_positiontype_id: cp4.id,
  salarystart: 1200,
  salaryend: 2000,
  category_country_id: cc1.id,
  city: 'accra',
  town: 'tesano estates',
  postcode: '1206',
  category_editorialapproval_id: ce1.id, 
  category_applicationrequest_id: car1.id,
  userr_id: u1.id,
  category_advert_id: ca3.id 
  )

Advert.delete_all
a2 = Advert.create!(
  title: 'management consultant',
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ac dapibus',
  category_jobtype_id: cj3.id,
  category_positiontype_id: cp1.id,
  salarystart: 2500,
  salaryend: 3000,
  category_country_id: cc1.id,
  city: 'accra',
  town: 'dzorwulu',
  postcode: '1206',
  category_editorialapproval_id: ce1.id, 
  category_applicationrequest_id: car1.id,
  userr_id: u1.id,
  category_advert_id: ca2.id 
  )

Advert.delete_all
a3 = Advert.create!(
  title: 'risk analyst',
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ac dapibus',
  category_jobtype_id: cj6.id,
  category_positiontype_id: cp2.id,
  salarystart: 1000,
  salaryend: 1500,
  category_country_id: cc2.id,
  city: 'lagos',
  town: 'leki',
  postcode: '1141',
  category_editorialapproval_id: ce1.id, 
  category_applicationrequest_id: car1.id,
  userr_id: u1.id,
  category_advert_id: ca4.id 
  )

Advert.delete_all
a4 = Advert.create!(
  title: 'business analyst',
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ac dapibus',
  category_jobtype_id: cj6.id,
  category_positiontype_id: cp2.id,
  salarystart: 2000,
  salaryend: 2500,
  category_country_id: cc2.id,
  city: 'lagos',
  town: 'victoria',
  postcode: '1223',
  category_editorialapproval_id: ce1.id, 
  category_applicationrequest_id: car1.id,
  userr_id: u1.id,
  category_advert_id: ca1.id 
  )

Advert.delete_all
a5 = Advert.create!(
  title: 'accountant',
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ac dapibus',
  category_jobtype_id: cj1.id,
  category_positiontype_id: cp4.id,
  salarystart: 1500,
  salaryend: 2500,
  category_country_id: cc1.id,
  city: 'accra',
  town: 'labone',
  postcode: '1209',
  category_editorialapproval_id: ce1.id, 
  category_applicationrequest_id: car1.id,
  userr_id: u1.id,
  category_advert_id: ca1.id 
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the documentation for formatting text in questions and answers. Correctly formatting code, code snippets, variable names in your question helps us help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because prior to each `Advert.create!` you're doing `Advert.delete_all` which deletes all the ones you'd previously created leaving only the last one undeleted.